# Why does CSS animation reset object's colour to original colour?

Tags: css, html

I was playing with CSS animation, making some text go from one colour to another. This would work but it would then finish off with putting the text back to the original colour of the text.  What's going on here and how do I stop it from happening?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}

#l0 {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    color: black;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="l0">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</body>
```

Do I have to also set the class of the object to say "stay at this colour"?

Comment: Why not just change `red` to `white` in that case? If you want everything else to be red, but this to be white, then target the `h1` specifically instead of the entire `body`.

Comment: @TylerRoper, because this is a simple sample.  Not exactly what I am doing, but this points out the crux of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of animation, to make the animated element retain the last value, you have to set the [animation fill mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to `forwards` like so

> animation-fill-mode: forwards

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}

#l0 {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    color: black;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="l0">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</body>
```